# Writing from EC2 to S3

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have a Java program that runs on Amazon EC2. I wanted the program to write it to S3. I wasnt able to find instructions on how to write to S3 from Amazon EC2. What  is the approach  I shoulduse ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you already using the AWS SDK for Java? If not you should download it. It doesn't matter whether you're writing to S3 from EC2 or from your laptop, you can write to it from Java easily enough using the SDK.

See the [TransferManager](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/TransferManager.html) class.

Answer (score 2):

1. [Mount](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=319538) the S3 volume on your EC2 host.
2. Use the standard Java io methods to write to the mount point.

Comment: That can be somewhat unpredictable as s3 doesn't behave as a block device.

Answer (score 1):

You can mount a S3 bucket as a partition and work with S3 files as they where located on your server's HDD.

I'm the lead developer and maintainer of Open source project [RioFS project](https://github.com/skoobe/riofs): an userspace filesystem to mount Amazon S3 buckets. You can use our project to mount and operate with files using Java or any other programming language.

Hope it helps !